Synchronous demodulation using balanced mixer IC
Can I use MC1496 balanced modulator/demodulator IC for synchronous demodulation by using it as multiplier for two sine waves(one signal and one carrier)
Asking it because the datasheet mention the follow
"These devices were designed for use where the output voltage is a
product of an input voltage (signal) and a switching function (carrier)"
Does this mean it is suitable for only a multiplication with square wave (some internal things optimised for square wave multiplication) ,does switching function here mean explicitly digital signal,or a generalized signal(sine or square).

MC1496 can be used as a multiplier between two sinewaves (see page 8 of the datasheet). However, the performance for other parameters like distortion, balance, leakage etc will not be as good as when it is used in switching mode. The performance will also not be as good as a multiplier designed to be used with sinewaves.
Try it out. It may well perform well enough in your application. If it doesn't, you'll have a better handle on what you do need from a multiplier, every experiment teaches you something.

sure i will carry on with it. Is there any bench mark standard to test against?

@dhuwarkesh There are several benchmarks. One is ideal performance, which the circuit will never achieve, but you may have difficulty measuring how far it falls short. The second benchmark is your requirement - what leakage do you need, offset stability, signal to noise and distortion ratio (note the upper 'carrier' inputs are only vaguely linear to 25 mV or so - see page 8 of the datasheet - which limits your dynamic range)

A single MC1496 may not be the best analog multiplier but it still beats most that can be achieved in a discrete circuit. You can combine 4 of them to get a much nicer multiplier, with second-order errors compensated for.

@kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I have seen a multiplier design using two lm1496 ,but not 4,can i get some link for reference?
